# Unable to obtain connection from database sqlserver://<host>:<port>;databaseName=<database> for user 'sa': Cannot open database

Tags: flyway

I am using flyway-6.0.6.
I am trying to connect SQL server and getting below error
ERROR:
Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:sqlserver://xxxx/yyyy) for user 'sa': Cannot open database "yyyy" requested by

### the login. The login failed.

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SQL State  : 28000
Error Code : 18456
Message    : Login failed for user 'sa'.

Comment: Usually Login failed for user 'sa' would simply mean your password is wrong.

Comment: You can check the event log on the database server for more information as to the exact cause of the login failure.